# How to overwrite layout settings in Drupal Zen sub theme?

Tags: theming

How to overwrite layout settings in Drupal Zen sub theme so that it can be changed by the sub theme itself? I found that in Zen core theme there is a comment as "Only toggle the layout for the main Zen theme". Does this mean we cannot enable this setting via our sub theme? Can anyone assist me on this?